# How would I locate a button element which are in the same list and have the same class but have different text on the button in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the html code from the website:

[Screenshot from inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwDwU.png)

Basically what I would like to do is to find the button but all of the buttons have the same class.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [Selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

You can locate it by xpath:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
mytext = "special button"
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="{}"]'.format(mytext))
```

To find a button that says "special button"

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I would like for the "Some text" to be a user input and when I do [text()=' +text  ']' it says that there's and error with ']'.

Comment: Use string formatting instead. Check updated answer

Comment: So they changed the website and they separated the button into different lines in the html.

Comment: How would i go about finding that button.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use the xpath and get the web element

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Buy  $100']"));
```